# resizeObserver vs intersectionObserver performance

Tags: javascript, performance, observers, intersection-observer

Whenever the dom changes in height (such as an ad loads and causes layout shift), I need to run a method on element X.

The lightest approaches dom-wise I could think of were  `resizeObserver` or `intersectionObserver`.

The `intersectionObserver` solution would permanently observe element X and runs the method when it is on screen. Downside is it'll run every time you scroll past it.

The `resizeObserver` solution would permanently observe the page's main container (holds all possible shifting elements) for height changes (dom shifting) and then runs the method. Down side is it could run multiple times during the loading of the page, but plus side is it won't run again after that.

Is there a way to test/know which approach is lighter on the dom overall? Because they would both be permanent observers.

Comment: There would be a single observer anyway? Don't worry about perfs before it's a real problem. Ps: resizeObserver could also fire every time the window is resized by the user.

Comment: I agree! But just to add to question I guess there could be multiple element X's, so there would be a intersectionObserver for each one, but no matter what only one for resizeObserver, so perhaps with that, resizeObserver would make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

you could debounce the resizeObserver callback so it runs once when the user finish resizing.

here is some examples: https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/